# Automatically set date in the front matter of a Jekyll page

Tags: github, jekyll

When I create a post, in the front matter I have to insert layout, title, date etc. My concern is regarding `date` front matter. It is very inconvenient to insert `date time` and `time offset` in date field manually.

I'm not able to figure out how to do this automatically. I want the front matter `date` to update automatically with system time.

Answer (score 3):

The `date` variable in [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) is an optional variable that you can set to be able to **override** the date that you set when you title your post according what Jekyll is looking for (i.e. 2019-12-14-post-title.md). It should only refer to the date the post was originally made, and **not** the current system date. Except for certain edge cases, you really shouldn't have to define `date` in the front matter.

You can use [Liquid templating](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/) to post the current time to a page by passing the `"now"` keyword to `date` in your liquid template as follows:

```
This page was last updated at {{ "now" | date: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" }}.
```

to get the the output:

```
This page was last updated at 2019-12-14 17:48.
```

However this method has a big drawback for Jekyll usage, because it will refer to the current date **when the page was last generated** from the template and not when the page is being visited by the user.

The best way to access the current system time is likely to use javascript instead. This is fairly easy depending on your familiarity with the language, but essentially you can make a `Date` object and then output the info you are looking to display. Here is a quick snippet I made that shows a couple methods that act on the Date object to output different values such as the date, time, and year:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>The toDateString() method converts a date to a date string:</h3>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<h3>The toLocaleTimeString() method outputs formatted time:</h3>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<h3>The getFullYear() method outputs the year:</h3>
<p id="demo3"></p>

<script>
// create date object
var d = new Date();

// use toDateString() to output formatted date
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = d.toDateString();

// use toLocaleTimeString() to output formatted time
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();

// use getFullYear() to output year
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = d.getFullYear();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

W3schools has a good rundown of the [Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) and how to [format output](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) if you need more examples and reference on usage.

If you need to know how to use Javascript with Jekyll there is a helpful post on [Jekyll Talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/add-custom-javascript-to-a-jekyll-page/789/4) that will help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not HAVE to insert 'layout, title, date etc'. You can use [Front Matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) for them. This only makes sense for the layout as the title can or should be default, nor the date.

The date MUST be set in your filename and can be overridden in the Front Matter. Please note that this is ONLY true for the built-in collection `posts`. If you use a custom collection you do not need a date at all.

However, if you choose to use `posts` nevertheless and you want to add the date automatically, there is only one real option: Use a CMS that automates this input, like Forestry.io or CloudCannon.

Comment: AFAIK you can commit back to the repo for free (and host elsewhere in the case of CloudCannon).